# Why doesn't Include have any effect?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, extension-methods

I am doing the following LINQ Query which works but doesn't return the navigation property Person filled, I get `null`.

```
public IEnumerable<SharePeople> GetSharePeopeByCarId(int carId)
{
    return from q in _context.Cars
           join s in _context.Shares 
               on q.CarId equals s.Car.CarId
           join p in _context.SharePeople.Include(p => p.Person) 
               on s.ShareId equals p.ShareId
           where q.CarId == carId
           select p;
}
```

I have no idea why, since when I do the regular extension method like `_context.SharePeople.Include(p => p.Person)` it works.

Comment: Are you certain  you have matches of the criteria `s.ShareId equals p.ShareId` ?

Comment: yes because I get one record, but the ``Person``property is null, all the other values are ok.

Comment: I have a ``Person``property inside ``SharePeople``.

Comment: has your context `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ste-fu approach it did not worked, but with a variation of it I was able to put it to work.

I guess Gert Arnold answered why it does not work, but since I got it working here is the code:

`var sharePeople = Context.SharePeople.Include("Person");`

`return sharePeople.Where(s => s.Shares.Car.CarId == carId);`

Answer (score 5):

[This post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include) clearly describes when `Include` does and doesn't have effect.

The critical part is the *shape* of the query, i.e. the selected columns. If anything changes the shape after an `Include`, the `Include` not longer works.

In your query the shape changes four times, in these statement parts:

1. `from q in _context.Cars`: the query would return only `Car` columns
2. `join s in _context.Shares`: `Car` + `Share` columns
3. `join p in _context.SharePeople`: `Car` + `Share` + `SharePeople` columns. **Here's the Include**.
4. `select p`, only `SharePeople` columns

Once you're aware of it, the remedy is simple:

```
(from q ... select p).Include(p => p.Person)
```

This also applies when the shape of the query seemingly doesn't change, but the query produces a projection. Suppose you'd have `select new { q, s, p }`. This would still select `Car` + `Share` + `SharePeople` columns, the same as before the `Include`. However, the query produces an anonymous type. This type *itself* doesn't have any navigation properties that could be populated by an `Include`, so again, the `Include` doesn't do anything. This is [by design](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/238).

Comment: plus one . This answer is great, clarify many things to me . Thanks a lot