# Override lazy loading on anonymous type with LINQ to entity

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have three entities generated by Entity Framework. One is `event` and this contains navigation properties called `frogs` and `user_bookings`. I posted a related question before about performing a sub-query which seems to work but it prevents me overriding lazy loading of a property.

```
var evts = from evt in context.events.Include("frogs")
           where evt.event_id < 10
           select evt;
```

This works - the navigation property `frogs` gets loaded.

However, when I alter the LINQ to this:

```
var evts = from evt in context.events.Include("frogs")
           where evt.event_id < 10
           select new
           {
               Event = evt,
               HasBooked = evt.user_bookings.Any(x => x.user_id == 1)
           };
```

I get an error trying to access the `frogs` because the ObjectContext no longer exists. I tried removing virtual from the class definition for the `event` class, but this just results in an empty list of frogs, when they are definitely there!

Comment: "because the ObjectContext no longer exists" why would that be? Certainly not because of some code posted here.

Comment: Yes, I think I know why the message appears. The data is trying to be fetched when I ask for it for the view that displays it, by which time it's been disposed of. My question is what do I need to do to get it to load the data at query time for the second option? I know I can add `include` in the first example, but that doesn't work for the second one, so my guess is that it's not in the right place when the `select new` part is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [by design](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2131). `Include` is ignored when the query result is a projection, *even when* the projection contains an entity that could contain the `Include`d properties.

I don't know why EF implemented it this way. If the projection doesn't contain any entities, but is just some type (anonymous or not), there is no `Include` target, so ignoring it makes sense. But if the projection does contain an `Include` target (`Event` in your case) it seems to me that they could have decided to make that work. But, well, they didn't.

Maybe it's because the rules when `Include` actually has an effect are [less obvious than you might expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29308569/861716). In your case, the shape of the query changes after the `Include`, so it's ignored.

You could work around this by also querying the `frogs`:

```
from evt in context.events.Include("frogs")
where evt.event_id < 10
select new
{
   Event = evt,
   Frogs = evt.frogs,
   HasBooked = evt.user_bookings.Any(x => x.user_id == 1)
};
```

Now each `Event` will also have its `frogs` collection filled (because of *relationship fixup*). But there are two gotchas. The collections are not *marked* as loaded, so -

- if lazy load can occur afterwards, it will occur, making the initial load useless.
- if lazy loading can't occur any more (because the context is disposed) you will get an exception.

This means that to make this work you have to disable lazy loading.

Comment: Thank you - that's a really detailed and helpful explanation.