# Navigation Properties Missing After Left Join

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to do a left join on two entities that have navigation properties. I have disabled lazy loading.

Here is my code:

```
var awis =
            from ai in Context.AdItems
                            .Include(ai => ai.Item)
                            .Include(ai => ai.Item.Buyer)
                            .Include(ai => ai.Item.OrderHeader)
                            .Where(ai => ai.AdYear == adYear && ai.AdNumber == adNumber)
            join si in Context.StoreItems
                            .Include(si => si.Store)
                            .Where(si => si.StoreId == storeId) on ai.ItemId equals si.ItemId into x
            from r in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new AdWeekItem
            {
                AdItemId = ai.AdItemId,
                AdItem = ai,
                StoreItemId = r == null ? 0 : r.StoreItemId,
                StoreItem = r
            };
```

The outer join works fine but I do not have my navigation properties included in the projected `AdWeekItem`.

That is, `AdWeekItem.AdItem.Item` is null, etc.

How do I include these navigation properties and do a left outer join?

Comment: I have explicitly disabled lazy loading. I do not want to use lazy loading.

Comment: Have you define appropriate foreign key in context creation?

Comment: `public int ItemId { get; set; } [ForeignKey(nameof(ItemId))]
public Item Item { get; set; }`

Comment: you should apply foreign key to foreign key property not navigation property like  
`[ForeignKey("Item")] public int ItemId { get; set; } public Item Item { get; set; }`

Comment: Here's what I have:

`/// <summary>
  /// A foreign key to the item.
  /// </summary>
  [ForeignKey(nameof(Item))]
  public int ItemId { get; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// A navigation property to the item.
  /// </summary>
  [ForeignKey(nameof(ItemId))]
  public Item Item { get; set; }`
I have both. This works for every other relationship In all my other queries, when I use the Include method.

Comment: Which EF version is this?

Comment: I'm running v6.2

Comment: OK, in EF <= 6,  Includes are always completely ignored in projections (`select new ...`).

Comment: So that should not be the problem, right?

Comment: Is there a way to efficiently join in my navigation properties _after_ the left join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EF6, `Include`s are [always ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29308569/861716) when a LINQ query ends in a projection (`select new ...`). Your only option is to explicitly query the navigation properties you want to have included and then project to the end result:

```
var temp = from ai in Context.AdItems
                             .Where(ai => ai.AdYear == adYear && ai.AdNumber == adNumber)
            join si in Context.StoreItems
                              .Where(si => si.StoreId == storeId) on ai.ItemId equals si.ItemId into x
            from r in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new 
            {
                AdItemId = ai.AdItemId,
                AdItem = ai,
                ai.Item,
                ai.Item.Buyer,
                ai.Item.OrderHeader,
                StoreItemId = r == null ? 0 : r.StoreItemId,
                StoreItem = r,
                r.Store
            };

var awis = from x in temp.AsEnumerable() // pull into memory and continue           
            select new AdWeekItem
            {
                AdItemId = x.AdItemId,
                AdItem = x.AdItem,
                StoreItemId = x.StoreItemId,
                StoreItem = x.StoreItem
            };
```

EF will have populated `AdItem.Item` etc. by *relationship fixup* (i.e. auto-population of navigation properties).